# Windows Named Semaphore Not Getting Locked

Tags: c++, winapi, ipc, semaphore

I am developing C++ class with calls to Windows API C libraries.

I am using the Semaphores for a task, let's say I have two processes:

ProcessA has two semaphores:

> Global\processA_receiving_semaphore
>
> Global\processA_waiting_semaphore

ProcessB has two semaphores:

> Global\processB_receiving_semaphore
>
> Global\processB_waiting_semaphore

I have two threads in each process:

Sending thread in processA:

> Wait on "Global\processB_waiting_semaphore"
>
> // do something
>
> Signal "Global\processB_receiving_semaphore"

Receiving thread on processB:

> Wait on "Global\processB_receiving_semaphore"
>
> // do something
>
> Signal "Global\processB_waiting_semaphore

I removed ALL code that Releases "Global\processB_waiting_semaphore" but it can still be acquired. Calling `WaitForSingleObject` on that semaphore always returns successful wait and immediately. I tried setting the timeout period to 0 and it still acquires the semaphore while NOTHING is releasing it.

The receiving semaphore has `initial count = 0` and `max count = 1` while the waiting semaphore has `initial count = 1` and `max count = 1`.

Calling `WaitForSingleObject` on the receiving semaphore works great and blocks until it is released by the other process. The problem is with the waiting semaphore and I cannot figure out why. The code is very big and I have made sure the names of the semaphores are set correctly.

Is this a common issue? If you need more explanation please comment and I will modify the post.

---

EDIT: CODE ADDED:

Receiver semaphores:

```
bool intr_process_comm::create_rcvr_semaphores()
{
  std::cout << "\n  Creating semaphore: " << "Global\\" << this_name << "_rcvr_sem";
  rcvr_sem = CreateSemaphore(NULL, 0, 1, ("Global\\" + this_name + "_rcvr_sem").c_str());

  std::cout << "\n  Creating semaphore: " << "Global\\" << this_name << "_wait_sem";
  wait_sem = CreateSemaphore(NULL, 1, 1, ("Global\\" + this_name + "_wait_sem").c_str());

  return (rcvr_sem && wait_sem);
}
```

Sender semaphores:

```
// this sender connects to the wait semaphore in the target process
sndr_sem = OpenSemaphore(SEMAPHORE_MODIFY_STATE, FALSE, ("Global\\" + target_name + "_wait_sem").c_str());
// this target connects to the receiver semaphore in the target process
trgt_sem = OpenSemaphore(SEMAPHORE_MODIFY_STATE, FALSE, ("Global\\" + target_name + "_rcvr_sem").c_str());

DWORD intr_process_locking::wait(unsigned long period)
{
   return WaitForSingleObject(sndr_sem, period);
}

void intr_process_locking::signal()
{
   ReleaseSemaphore(trgt_sem, 1, 0);
}
```

Receiving thread function:

```
void intr_process_comm::rcvr_thread_proc()
{
  while (conn_state == intr_process_comm::opened) {
    try {
      // wait on rcvr_semaphore for an infinite time
      WaitForSingleObject(rcvr_sem, INFINITE);
      if (inner_release) // if the semaphore was released within this process
        return;
      // once signaled by another process, get the message
      std::string msg_str((LPCSTR)hmf_mapview);
      // signal one of the waiters that want to put messages 
      // in this process's memory area
      // 
      // this doesn't change ANYTHING in execution, commented or not..
      //ReleaseSemaphore(wait_sem, 1, 0);

      // put this message in this process's queue
      Msg msg = Msg::from_xml(msg_str);
      if (msg.command == "connection")
        process_connection_message(msg);
  
      in_messages.enQ(msg);
      //std::cout << "\n  Message: \n"<< msg << "\n";
    }
    catch (std::exception e) {
      std::cout << "\n  Ran into trouble getting the message. Details: " << e.what();
    }
  }
}
```

Sending thread function:

```
void intr_process_comm::sndr_thread_proc()
{
  while (conn_state == intr_process_comm::opened ||
    (conn_state == intr_process_comm::closing && out_messages.size() > 0)
    ) {
    // pull a message out of the queue
    Msg msg = out_messages.deQ();

    if (connections.find(msg.destination) == connections.end())
      connections[msg.destination].connect(msg.destination);

    if (connections[msg.destination].connect(msg.destination)
      != intr_process_locking::state::opened) {
      blocked_messages[msg.destination].push_back(msg);
      continue;
    }

    // THIS ALWAYS GETS GETS WAIT_OBJECT_0 RESULT
    DWORD wait_result = connections[msg.destination].wait(wait_timeout);
    if (wait_result == WAIT_TIMEOUT) {  // <---- THIS IS NEVER TRUE
      out_messages.enQ(msg);
      continue;
    }
    // do things here
    // release the receiver semaphore in the other process
    connections[msg.destination].signal();
  }
}
```

To clarify some things:

`trgt_sem` in a sender is the `rcvr_sem` in the receiver.

`sndr_sem' in the sender is the 'wait_sem" in the receiver.

Comment: general question - why you here use exactly semaphore instead event ?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] showing what you are actually doing.  Don't describe the code, show it.

Comment: @RbMm I have a buffer with single consumer and multiple producers.

Comment: @RemyLebeau There you go, the code. Cannot put less and a bit more would be too much.

Comment: `OpenSemaphore(SEMAPHORE_MODIFY_STATE,` already error. you can not wait on this object. any call to wait function with this object must fail with error access denied. you need use `SYNCHRONIZE|SEMAPHORE_MODIFY_STATE`

Comment: @RbMm I love you. That did it. Thanks a TON!

Comment: but you can not got `WAIT_OBJECT_0` from `WaitForSingleObject`. you must got `WAIT_FAILED` and `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`

Comment: @RbMm Apparently I was. But I wasn't checking correctly as you can see in the code. Can you write an answer explaining all of these things so I can select it for this question?

Comment: @Everyone - but I still not understand why you using semaphore here. use it with `lMaximumCount==1` - valid, but in this case it functional like event object

Comment: @RbMm I might increase the semaphore count to get better performance. I am implementing my own `ipc` library and trying to get best performance results with different test cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for call [`WaitForSingleObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687032(v=vs.85).aspx) with some handle:

> The handle must have the **`SYNCHRONIZE`** access right.

but you open semaphore with **`SEMAPHORE_MODIFY_STATE`** access only. with this access possible call [`ReleaseSemaphore`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685071(v=vs.85).aspx) (This handle must have the **`SEMAPHORE_MODIFY_STATE`** access right) but call to [`WaitForSingleObject`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687032(v=vs.85).aspx) fail with result `WAIT_FAILED`. call to `GetLastError()` after this must return `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`.

so if we want call both [`ReleaseSemaphore`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685071(v=vs.85).aspx) and any wait function - we need have **`SEMAPHORE_MODIFY_STATE | SYNCHRONIZE`** access on handle. so need open with code

`OpenSemaphore(SEMAPHORE_MODIFY_STATE|SYNCHRONIZE, )`

and of course always checking api return values and error codes can save a lot of time

Answer (score 0):

If you set the timeout to 0 WaitForSingleObject will always return immediately, a successful WaitForSingleObject will return WAIT_OBJECT_0 (which happens to have the value 0), WFSO is not like most APIs where success is indicated by a non-zero return.

Comment: That `is` what I meant when I said it is always successful. I know it will return if the wait-period was 0. But my problem is that it always returns with `WAIT_OBJECT_0` despite the semaphore not being released.